# Custom JsonObjectRequest

Tags: android, android-volley

I created the below Custom JsonObjectRequest and I just that want to send always a header with parameters for authorization to access on server

```
public class RequestController extends JsonObjectRequest {

public RequestController(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonParams, 
                         Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, jsonParams, listener, errorListener);

}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put("Authorization", MyApplication.getWebServiceKey());
    headers.put("Content-Type","application/json");
    return headers;
}
```

}

This is also the RequestManager to call the customRequest

public class RequestManager {

```
private static final String TAG = "RequestManager";
private Context context;
private RequestInterface requestInterface;
private final Gson gson = new Gson();

public RequestManager(Context paramContext, RequestInterface requestInterfaceParam) {
    this.context = paramContext;
    this.requestInterface = requestInterfaceParam;
}

public void makeRequest(int method, String req_url, JSONObject jsonParams){
    String url = NetworkManager.BASE_URL + req_url;
    RequestController requestController = new RequestController(method, url, jsonParams,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.toString());
                    if(response.optBoolean("status"))
                        requestInterface.onSuccess(response.toString());
                    else
                        requestInterface.onError(response.optJSONArray("errors").toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "onErrorResponse: " + new String(error.networkResponse.data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            requestInterface.onNetworkError(error.toString());
        }
    });
    NetworkManager.getInstance(context).getRequestQueue().add(requestController);
}
```

}

With GET method it is always OK but when I send it with POST method the jsonParams doens't send it. I don't know why...

I implemented this here

```
    JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
    body.put("type", typeRegister);
    body.put("identityDocumentNumber", "123");
    body.put("email", "joselo@gmail.com");
    body.put("phone", "123");
    body.put("password", "12345678");
    body.put("passwordConfirmation", "12345678");
    RequestManager requestManager = new RequestManager(SignUpActivity.this, this);
    requestManager.makeRequest(Request.Method.POST, "/users", body);
```

I tried to implement StringRequest but I get the same result,  Map but no luck. It doesnt work. I tried using getParams method to implement it, but yet it doesn't work. I don't know what it could be wrong.

Edit: I solved this with adding this changes to my RequestController

```
@Override
public byte[] getBody() {
    return postString != null ? postString.getBytes(Charset
            .forName("UTF-8")) : super.getBody();
}

@Override
public String getBodyContentType() {
    return postString !=null?"application/json; charset=utf-8":super.getBodyContentType();
}
```

this is because my RequestController extends JsonObjectRequest and it extends Request and use getBody instead getParams for this reason getParams is ignored but with that i solved

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
try{
    JSONObject jsonBody =new JSONObject("{\n" +
                "\"type\", typeRegister,\n" +
                "\"identityDocumentNumber\":\"123\",\n" +
                "\"email\":\"joselo@gmail.com\",\n" +
                "\"phone\":\"123\",\n" +
                "\"password\":\"12345678\",\n" +
                "\"passwordConfirmation\":\"12345678\"\n" +
                "}");

    RequestQueue mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(LookUp.url, jsonBody,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.toString());


                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }

    }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Authorization", MyApplication.getWebServiceKey());
            headers.put("Content-Type","application/json");
            return headers;
        }
    };

    mQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

    }
    catch (JSONException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("ERROR",ex.getMessage());
        pDialog.cancel();
    }
```

Comment: nope it doenst work, i think that its when put the headers it replace params or something like this

Comment: "nope it doesn't work" doesn't clarify your situation, have you tried debugging? if so what is the response/error message. Try adding breakpoints in onResponse and onErrorResponse to check the response

Comment: I solved this in  my RequestController extends JsonObjectRequest and it extends Request and use getBody instead getParams for this reason getParams is ignored but with that i solved